# How long does the "new" indicator show up next to a task in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint

When creating a task in SharePoint 2010, the "new" indicator is shown after creating a task. How long is this displayed and is the amount of time it is displayed configurable from the GUI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;825510&Product=spts

The default, AFAIK is 2 days.

[Edit]
Just verified, and can say confidently that it is 2 days.

stsadm -o getproperty -pn days-to-show-new-icon -url http://localhost

< Property Exist="Yes" Value="2" />

If you have to change it, use setproperty instead of get.

Answer (score 0):

It is configurable using STSADM, I believe it's 24 hours by default